# clickhouse distributed problem

Tags: clickhouse

Есть 2 виртуальные машины (ubuntu 14.04), соединенные сеткой (пингуются без проблем), на них установлен clickhouse. Я делаю следующее на одной из ВМ:

```
create database test

create table if not exists test.ontime_local ( 
    ipS String, 
    ipD String, 
    status String, 
    time DateTime, 
    id UInt32
) ENGINE = Log

create table if not exists test.ontime_all AS test.ontime_local ENGINE = Distributed(test, '', ontime_local, rand())
```

Там же правлю конфигурационный файл:

```
<remote_servers>
    <test>     
        <shard>  
            <replica>
                <host>192.168.75.129</host>
                <port>9000</port>
                <default_database>test</default_database>
            </replica> 
        </shard>
    </test>
</remote_servers>
```

На другой ВМ создаю БД и там локальную таблицу:

```
create database test

create table test.ontime_local(
    ipS String, 
    ipD String, 
    status String, 
    time DateTime, 
    id UInt32
 ) ENGINE = Log;
```

Также закинул пару строк для теста.

И возжелал, чтобы с первой ВМ я отправил запрос:

```
select * from test.ontime_all
```

и получил тестовые строки из таблицы, которая расположена на второй ВМ (по сути получилась распределенная обработка на кластере).

Но выдает вот что:

> Received exception from server:
>   Code: 279. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1.
>   DB::NetException. DB::NetException: All connection tries failed. Log:
>   Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (192.168.75.129:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
>   Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (192.168.75.129:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException
>   Code: 210, e.displayText() = DB::NetException: Connection refused: (192.168.75.129:9000), e.what() = DB::NetException

Мучился-мучился, но решения так и не нашел. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58947/discussion-on-question-by-se-pro-clickhouse-distributed-problem).

Answer (score 1):

из комментария [@Se.Pro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/248582/se-pro):

> Проблема в том, что первая ВМ слушала 9000 порт, а вторая ВМ слушала только себя(спать надо больше и не тупить). Для тех, кто вдруг столкнется с такой проблемой, добавьте `<listen_host>::</listen_host>` в `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml` на всех компьютерах, объединенных в кластер